# Unable to record Speaker Output using Audacity in 22.04

Tags: sound, alsa, 22.04, audio-recording, audacity

It has been a while since I have used Audacity. It was asking for some permission related to ALSA at the beginning, which I allowed. Not sure whether related to that, I do not see any option to choose Stereo Mix which was available before.

Is there any method to record what is playing through the speaker using Audacity? Thanks.

Comment: Audacity is now snap, like so many others. So you may need to enable additional permissions. Just open Ubuntu Software, serach for and open the software's page, click Permissions.

Comment: I just added all permissions except the one for jack and writing on removable drives. And did a shutdown and start. But it is still  the same

Comment: I downloaded the AppImage but still do not see the Stereo Mix option. Thanks